# How can I get unicode output in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a main function that outputs unicode which looks like this:

```
main = do
    hSetEncoding stdout utf8
    input <- getContents
    mapM_ putStr $ myfunc input
```

How can I write this function without do notation?

I get `<stdout>: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)` when I try to compile this main function:

```
main = getContents >>= mapM_ putStr . myfunc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use sequence (>>):

```
main = do
    hSetEncoding stdout utf8
    input <- getContents
    mapM_ putStr $ myfunc input

~~>

main = hSetEncoding stdout utf8 >> getContents >>= \input -> mapM_ putStr $ lines input

~~>

main = hSetEncoding stdout utf8 >> getContents >>= mapM_ putStr . lines
```